# "Fading in" new layers in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10196.pdf) paper in Keras, with a tensorflow backend.

In my understanding, they progressively grow a GAN, fading in additional blocks of layers as the model is trained. New layers are faded in linearly over iterations.

I'm not sure how to introduce the "fading in" they used.

To do this Keras, I'm thinking I'll probably need a Lambda layer -- but that's about as much as I know.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use [Keras Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). That way you can rearrange the inputs to the layer as well as the outputs and interconnect them the way you want to while the layers keep the weights they learned. You will have to have a few nested if-statements, but I think it should work.

Or you could have all the models prepared (functions that return you the model architecture and can set layer weights) and just populate layers in the new model with weights from corresponding layers from the old model.